# How is the discrete metric continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, metric-spaces

It is [proven](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Metric_is_Continuous) that any metric $d$ is continuous. 
Consider the metric space $(\mathbb{R}, d)$ where:

$$d:\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$$

$$d(x, y) =  \begin{cases} 
      0 & x=y \\
      1 & x\neq y
   \end{cases}
$$

Let $x_n \rightarrow x=0$ and $y_n \rightarrow y=0$. If you take $d(x_n, y_n)\rightarrow 1 \neq 0=d(x, y)$. This shows that this metric is discontinuous. What is wrong with my reasoning?

Comment: $x_n=0=y_n$ for all $n$ large.

Comment: You write $\mathbb{R}$ but it has two different topologies for this statement. See my answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The fact that $d(x_{n},x)\to 0$ implies that eventually $d(x_{n},x)<1/2$. Thus, eventually the $x_{n}$'s must all be $0$. The same goes for the $y_{n}$'s. Therefore, $d(x_{n},y_{n})$ is eventually $0$ for such sequences.

Answer (score 6):

You misrepresent the statement.

Correct is: let $(X,d)$ be a metric space. This induces a topology $\mathcal{T}_d$ on $X$ induced by the metric (the minimal topology where all balls $B(x,r)$ are open). Then the map $d: (X,\mathcal{T}_d) \times (X,\mathcal{T}_d) \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous where the left hand side has the product topology of *the metric topology* with itself and the reals have the usual Euclidean topology.

If we use the discrete metric, which induces the discrete topology, then this product topology is also discrete and $d$ is indeed continuous (as is any map on a discrete space, so it's not very informative).

Answer (score 2):

A sequence $x_n$ has limit $0$ in the discrete metric if and only if eventually $x_n = 0$. Does this help?

Comment: Why is that so? Isn't $x_n$ a normal sequence such as $\frac{1}{n}$? In which case $x_n\neq 0 \forall n$?

Comment: Ok, understood what you mean with the help of ervx's answer :) thanks